# How can I get visitors IP by Node.js?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have my own VPS server and I have script in Node.js which display the visitor's IP but always when I visit website I get in console local IP address (127.0.0.1). I use Nginx.

*Any idea?*

**Node.js script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

  const http = require('http');

  const host = '127.0.0.1';

  const port = 8080;

  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  res.statusCode = 200;

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

  var ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',').pop().trim() || 
  req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress || req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;


console.log(`IP = ${ip}`);

});

server.listen(port, host);
```

**Nginx proxy/headers configuration:**

```
server {

  listen 80 default_server;

  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

    
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name _;

  location / {
            
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Does your `node.js` project, have logger, like `morgan`?  If you have `http` server, not `https` then why do you need `nginx` and port forwarding? Why couldn't you open :80 port on your VPS and just launch you script via `npm`? If you does such things, will `console.log(${ip}`)` still shows you `127.0.0.1` or not?

Comment: I need to do it with Nginx

Answer (score 1):

You need to rig your nginx reverse proxy to pass along the requester's IP address. Adding these two settings to `nginx.conf` does the trick.

```
   proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Put these lines in your `location{...}` stanza of `nginx.conf` along with your `proxy-pass` and the rest.

With these changes, nginx inserts two http headers into each request: [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) and X-Real-IP.  (There's a new standard [Forwarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded): header, but nginx doesn't handle it easily as of mid-2020.)

Then, use `app.set()` to add [proxy server support](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) to your nodejs program to interpret those headers. Put this line in your `www` or `http-server.js` Javascript program shortly after your `const app = express()` line.

```
app.set( 'trust proxy', 'loopback' )
```

Express will then muck around with the X-Forwarded-For header for you and put the appropriate IP address in `req.ip`.

I've linked to some documentation. You would be wise to read it.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you show me how code should look like because I don't quite understand it.

Comment: I try this few times but don' work for me. Can you show code? I try